# Error - unbound symbol modulo (Scheme) when using Repl online IDE

Tags: ide, scheme, replit

A homework problem needs me to calculate gcd of 2 numbers. But using the modulo keyword in the function for gcd gives the above error when run on Repl.it (online IDE).

I looked at other answers, but they don't exactly provide a solution to the problem. I tried to run the program using jdoodle.com (another online IDE) and it works perfectly there. So, I don't know why it won't work on Repl.

```
;; My gcd function

(define (gcd a b)
  (cond 
    [
      (= b 0) a
    ]

    [else 
      (gcd b (modulo a b))
    ]
  )
)
```

I would like to know why this doesn't work for Repl IDE and if there is any way how I can make it work there without simply switching to another website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modulo` function is not implemented in BiwaScheme used by repl.it. However good new is - `mod` function is! So, with some reasonable reformatting, this should work:

```
(define (gcd a b)
   (cond [(= b 0) a]
         [else (gcd b (mod a b))]))
```

Comment: I tried it out. `mod` indeed does work for repl. Thank you.

Comment: Also, about the weird formatting I had used, I am new to Scheme, so I am just being extra careful with the brackets :)

Comment: The reason why is that BiwaScheme follows R6RS which has `mod` and `mod0`, while OP tries `modulo` which is defined in the previous standard, R5RS. Other programming languages has incompatible major versions as well, eg. Python 2 vs 3.